# How do I set this up in vb?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that checks if left click is held down then it starts a timer if its held down. I wanted something so if it detects that right click is held down, it stops the timer that the left click started

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    hotkey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton)
    If CBool(hotkey) = True Then
        Timer1.Start()
    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

For some reason, when I use the same code but just change `LButton` to `RButton`, it does not work

Comment: if you have done the first part, then second should be easy (and similar)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    hotkey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RButton)
    If CBool(hotkey) = True Then
        Timer1.Stop()
    Else
        Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub
```